# How to differentiates on non-scalar variable?

Tags: neural-networks, vector-analysis

I am new to PyTorch and Neural Network in general. I am following this tutorial: http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html#gradients

There are two examples of differentiation using `backward()`: one for scalar and one for non-scalar variable.

The scalar example:
[image]

The non-scalar example:

```
x = torch.randn(3) # input is taken randomly
x = Variable(x, requires_grad=True)

y = x * 2

c = 0
while y.data.norm() < 1000:
    y = y * 2
    c += 1

gradients = torch.FloatTensor([0.1, 1.0, 0.0001]) # specifying gradient because input is non-scalar
y.backward(gradients)

print(c)
print(x.grad)
```

Output:

```
9

102.4000
1024.0000
0.1024
```

I tried to understand it as I did for scalar example:
[image]

But, I can't figure out how it works.
I get exact same output for different values of `c` regardless of the input values:

```
8
51.2000
512.0000
0.0512

10
204.8000
2048.0000
0.2048
```

Please explain how it is calculating `y.backward(gradients)`

Source:
http://pytorch.org/docs/master/autograd.html#torch.autograd.Variable.backw

Comment: did you google "gradient" already? there's a ton of stuff on this subject. what exactly is unclear to you?

Comment: For gradients `0.1, 1.0, 0.0001` how `y.backward(gradients)` is computed?

Comment: You need to narrow down the question. Back prop is extensively discussed everywhere in ML. What aspect of it is a problem here?

Comment: I know the math behind getting `4.5000  4.5000 4.5000  4.5000` for scalar example (shown above). Can you explain the math behind getting `102.4000 1024.0000 0.1024` for non-scalar example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem:

[The non-scalar example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqHyH.png)